# Salesforce Opportunity Activity on All Opportunities in Account

Tags: salesforce

I am trying to setup my opportunities so that all of the opportunities within a given account share all of the same activity ("log a call" notes). In other words, if I had 5 opportunities associated with 1 account and I logged a call on one of those opportunities, the note I created would then show up on all of the other 4 opportunities automatically. Is there a way to do this or an alternative solution that would accomplish a similar goal?

Answer (score 0):

You can create trigger which will copy the note to all other opportunities related to the account.